# Dell XPS 15 - Trackpad Sensitivity

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, dell, synaptics

I feel like this issue has been raised hundreds of times, but my trackpad is way too sensitive!

I've attempted to change the trackpad sensitivity by setting the "Synaptics Finger" values through "xinput" (as suggested here: [Synaptics Touchpad community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) and elsewhere), but these values do not seem to make any difference.

For example, I can enter:

```
xinput --set-props 13 "Synaptics Finger" 1000 1000 1000
```

(13 being the index of my trackpad) into a terminal and there is no noticeable sensitivity difference. However, when I lest props, the "Synaptics Finger" values are listed as 1000 1000 1000.

Furthermore, these Synaptics Finger values are all reset to default values after a reboot.

If anyone has some insight with changing trackpad sensitivity for a Dell XPS 15 (Ubuntu 16.04) it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: my xps13 9370 touchpad is not sensitiv enough. its not reacting as fast to my finger as the macbook pro

Answer (score 0):

There is a sensitivity option for the touchpad under:

`Settings -> Devices -> Mouse & Touchpad`

works perfectly fine with Ubuntu 19.04 on my Dell XPS (9570)